# If I have multiple programs open and my curosor goes off of that program it doesn't stay on top

Tags: windows

For example, if I have chrome open, I hit calculator, if my cursor moves outside of the calculator program perimeters, it goes behind chrome. This happens will all programs. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel and find Ease of Access Centre. Click "Make the mouse easier to use". Under there you will find "Activate a window by hovering over it with a mouse". Remove checkmark and click "Apply". That should do it :-)

Comment: I was thinking xmouse, don't know if that's still a thing...

Comment: Oh I remember that! Still seems to exist, but MS is now providing the this behavior in the OS itself :-)

Comment: Oh.my.god. I have googled the heck trying to find that answer. THANK YOU ! That solved it Peregrino.!  You have no idea how much frustration you just fixed my life! THANK YOU THANK YOU!

Comment: LOL you're very welcome :-D Would you be kind and accept the answer?

Comment: ... btw, yeah, I actually do :-D